Does PackageManager#GET_META_DATA flag help to reduce the size in getInstalledApplications() method?
In my application I use the following method to get the list of apps installed in the system.
packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);

Due to this sometimes the following exception occurred-
AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 526696 bytes

To avoid this I have modified the code as below,
List<ApplicationInfo> applicationInfoList = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

Could you please help to understand the following points?

Does usage of getInstalledApplications() instead of getInstalledPackages() helps to reduce the size of received size?
What does the flag PackageManager.GET_META_DATA filter here? The definition from Android document is NOT clear to me-"Additional meta-data associated with this component. This field will only be filled in if you set the PackageManager#GET_META_DATA flag when requesting the info."


I am guessing that these questions stem from your earlier question, which I marked as a duplicate of this 10-year-old question.

Does usage of getInstalledApplications() instead of getInstalledPackages() helps to reduce the size of received size?

There should be fewer applications than packages, as "packages" could include some pre-installed items that do not qualify as "applications". This may not make a huge difference, but it might help.

What does the flag PackageManager.GET_META_DATA filter here?

In the context of getInstalledApplications(), including GET_META_DATA will return the details of any <meta-data> elements inside the <application> element in the manifests of those applications. Unless you need this information, I recommend not including this flag.
More generally, you need to determine what it is that you are trying to accomplish, then identify the best PackageManager methods to return you the least information that let you accomplish your aims.

I just need to get the list of installed applications and fetch the label and icon for the applications. Could you please help to understand how we can get the least possible data from package manager to achieve this? Is it possible to get just the list of packages?

@Dev_Cob: Use getInstalledApplications(0) and hope for the best. They really need to add a paginated API for this.

I have modified my code as below-
List applicationInfoList = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(0);
for (ApplicationInfo applicationInfo : applicationInfoList) {
String label = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo).toString();
Drawable icon = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(applicationInfo);
String packageName = applicationInfo.packageName; }
Would it ensure that TransactionTooLargeException won't happen? Is there still a chance to improve this? Thanks in advance.

@Dev_Cob: "Would it ensure that TransactionTooLargeException won't happen?" -- no. The PackageManager API is not designed for people with large numbers of installed apps. You can try to minimize the likelihood of a TransactionTooLargeException, but you cannot eliminate it. Off the cuff, I do not know of a better approach to what you are trying to do.

OK, I understood this point. I could reproduce the issue in another app. From log I see "E JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 534012)" followed by "Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 526696 bytes". I have noticed that this happens when we load 8 drawables to the binder in onCreateView of a fragment. Currently, I am loading the icons like this for 8 files-" binding.setting.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.settings_l_n);".  Could u pls suggest how to optimize the code to avoid exception?
